# Is it possible to have an external developer in Xcode just using exported cert+prov

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-id, development

Is it possible to have an external developer in Xcode without being logged in with an account, but using a exported certificate and provisioning profile?
Is it possible to select an imported certificate and provisioning profile without signing in with the account in Xcode?

We do not want him to have access to our Apple developer account, but need him to use a specific provisioning profile, to be able to send out test versions.

How do you solve this?

Comment: He can export the app using his account and then re-sign it using your certificates. [Here is one guide](http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/), or you can use [the xcbuild tool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6921689/1457385). Opinion based: A saver way is to make him a team member and adjust his permissions according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input but we do just not want him as a part of the team account because the app, though it is published on the team account, the app is moving out of the company.

And it is not possible to move the app to an other account because it once used iCloud.

We ended creating a new developer account just to send test versions out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want him to have limited, handing your cert is not the way to go.
Add him as a team member on iTunes Connect, adjust his permissions and remove him when the QA ends.

To add a second user to your account:

- https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/users_roles

Add the Apple ID for the person you want to be able to sign and don't let them upload.  This works for individual accounts as well as enterprise / corporate accounts.

Comment: This is only possible with a company (corporate) Developer enrollment, not for individual Developer enrollments.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I've never run into that limitation. See my edit to this answer haw to add a second account with different roles.

Comment: Thanks for the input but we do just not want him as a part of the team account.